# landing page does not load with 'exact' parameter in Route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to React, might be a simple and quick solution.

please check the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAlz5O2x7RQ

I am having an issue with loading of the landing page when the app starts(with the `exact` parameter), when the page loads only the menu appears but not the Home component(since the menu is outside the switch component), if I remove 'exact' from the path of the home page, the page loads fine but links don't work, then if I add `exact` parameter to the home page path while the app is running and refresh the output, it works and links work too, but if I restart with `exact`, home page does not load.

PS: I have tried strict and exact, I have only done two links of the menu.

I have read articles online, watched videos, and searched for questions here but could not find the answer.

here is the code.TIA

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Menu from './components/Menu';
import About from './components/About';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Router>
        <Menu />
        <Switch>
          <Route strict exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/about' component={About} />  
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      {/* <Home /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

***Menu component***

import React from 'react';
import logo from '../Assets/logoNew.png'
// import About from './About';
import './Menu.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <div className='menu-container'>
            <div className="menu-logo">
                <img src={logo} alt="Image not found" />
            </div>

            <div className="menu-block" >
                <ul>
                  <Link exact to='/'><li className="menu-link" > Home </li></Link>
                  <Link to='/about'><li className="menu-link" > About </li></Link>
                    <li className="menu-link" > Services </li>
                    <li className="menu-link" > Portfolio </li>
                    <li className="menu-link" > Pricing </li>
                    <li className="menu-link" > Blog </li>
                    <li className="menu-link" > Contact </li>
                </ul >
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default Menu;


***Home component***

import React from 'react';
import './Home.css'
import pic3nbg from '../MyPics/pic3nbg.png'


const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className="home-container">
            <div className="hero-image">
                <img src={pic3nbg} alt="Hero Pic not displayed" />
            </div>
            <div className="main-section-text">
                <div className="text-button">
                    <p>Hi there!</p>
                    <div className="square"></div>
                </div>
                <div className="about-me">
                    <h2>My Name is Leo</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="para-me">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Maxime rem perspiciatis consequatur dignissimos!
                </div>

                <div className="buttons-grp">
                    <button className='hire'>Hire Me <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
                    <button className='portfolio'>View Portfolio <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
                </div>

                <div className="social-media">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    );
};


export default Home;

***About Component ***

import React from 'react';
import './About.css'
import img from '../MyPics/pic1.png'

const About = () => {
    return (
        <div className='about-main'>
            <About> section *mostly text*
        </div>
    );
};



export default About;
```

Comment: `path="/"` and `exact` alone should work with the order you have the routes. Is one of these `Home` or `About` components, or the `Menu` rendering another router? Can you share these other components' code?

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks replying to my question, all the components <Menu />, <Home /> and <About /t> are not house to and are independent of each other, all of these components are imported and rendered in App.js. If you still want to have a look at them, I can post them.

Comment: Yes please, all part of a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: whats the best way to provide minimal, complete, and reproducible code? not sure how it works with React.

Comment: Usually including all the relevant code as properly formatted code snippets similar to what you've already provided. If you can also provide *running* code that reproduces the issue in a codesandbox that is generally also great additional sources to link to in your question as it saves people a step doing it themselves.

Comment: I tried to load the react app to codesandbox, but the src folder and contents are not downloading to sandbox. There is not much resource available for codesandbox as well, so I 'll add the code for each component here.

Comment: react-router-dom v5?

Comment: btw for minimal code, you can reduce your components that arent so relevant like the about page to something like this: `export const About = () => <div>About page</div>`

Comment: https://ash2686.github.io/myPortfolioDemo/ is the output

Comment: hey steve, its ^5.3.0

Comment: As I said, I don't see any overt issues and the code runs without issue here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/landing-page-does-not-load-with-exact-parameter-in-route-component-vrwn2), even with the `exact` prop and routes not in order.

Comment: Yeah works here it seems: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-alex-ojpji

I think it's a ghpages issue then. I've had plenty of trouble with the paths there. You'll need to account for the `/myPortfolioDemo/` in the prod environment. You might like to look into the match tool in react router, or look at the config for ghpages.

Comment: Try deploying it with Vercel and see if the issue disappears.

Comment: That was going to be my next question, if you were hosting this app somewhere in a subdirectory. If so then you might also add the subdirectory as the [basename](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) to the router. This would explain why "/" works, but anything deeper doesn't.

Comment: I've added a video of app not working, I am having this same issue locally on my PC, I have only used gh pages so far

Comment: In that video you are in *some* "/myPortfolioDemo" directory.

Comment: I don't have a folder with this name, anywhere in the root folder or any other folders,

Answer (score 0):

thanks Drew for spotting the bug from the video, in my package.json file I had set the
"homepage" : http://(github username).github.io/(name of repository)

in the above line (name of the repository) was causing this issue and was not needed apparently as I removed it and now the app is working just fine.